# Toggling boolean value, but just once? (java)

Tags: java, boolean, toggle

Every now and then there is a need to store a boolean value only once (to record that it has changed from false to true or vice versa) in a loop, while executing the loop to the end but not caring anymore about changes in the boolean value. Example:

```
    public static boolean dbDelete(Collection argObjectCollectionToDelete) {
        boolean result = true;
        for (Object object : argObjectCollectionToDelete) {
            boolean dbDelete = dbDelete(object);
            if (!dbDelete) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Is there some way to execute the equivalent of the code

```
if (!dbDelete) {
    result = false;
}
```

or

```
if (!dbDelete && !result) {
    result = false;
}
```

in a more elegant way, preferrably in one line?

Comment: The flip side is `b |= method()` if any method returns true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
result &= dbDelete(object);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result = result & dbDelete(object);
```

So it will only be true if `result` was *previously* true and `dbDelete` returned true.

Comment: Definitely shorter than my answer, but for me at least, more difficult to read.

Comment: @nfechner: Compound assignments are an acquired taste, but I think it's worth at least becoming somewhat comfortable with them, even if you don't use them much yourself. Just occasionally something like this can make a *huge* difference - particularly in situations where you can use a single expression but not an `if` block.

Comment: Very nice, I was after something like this. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!dbDelete(object)) {
    result = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

result = dbDelete(object) ? result : false;

Comment: "while executing the loop to the end but not caring anymore about changes in the boolean value"

Comment: I just updated it. Now it can only flip from true to false, and never back to true.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting more meaning into your variable names - it makes things easier.

```
public static boolean dbDelete(Collection argObjectCollectionToDelete) {
    boolean completedSuccessfully = true;
    for (Object object : argObjectCollectionToDelete) {
        boolean dbDelete = dbDelete(object);
        if (completedSuccessfully && !dbDelete) {  //won't change anymore after failure
            completedSuccessfully = false;
        }
    }
    return completedSuccessfully;
}
```